# Installing Matlab from an ISO image

Tags: mount, software-installation, directory-structure

I was trying to install Matlab, and used the following commands:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/disk
# mount -o loop R2014a_UNIX.iso /mnt/disk
# cd /mnt/disk
# ls -l
# ./install
```

However, I don't want it in a directory called disk, I want it in a directory called Matlab using

```
  mkdir /mnt/matlab
  mount -o ro,loop ./R2014a_UNIX.iso /mnt/matlab
  /mnt/matlab/install
  umount /mnt/matlab
```

(out of interest is this the best place to install it?)

However, I am unable to uninstall or remove /mnt or /mnt/disk as they have read only privileges. My searching and attempts with chown, rmdir and rm -r have not helped yet.

Please could you help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to install additional software packages in linux is `/opt/`. So create a directory for MatLab there and install it.

```
# mkdir /opt/matlab
# mount -o ro,loop ./R2014a_UNIX.iso /media/cdrom
# /media/cdrom/install
# umount /media/cdrom
```

As your installer is in the form of an ISO image, mount it in `/media/cdrom`.

I hope the installer `/media/cdrom/install` will ask you the location of installation and specify it as `/opt/matlab`. Once things are done set the `PATH` environment variable appropriately so that the `matlab` binaries are accessible without their "absolute path".

Why do u want to remove `/mnt/` directory ?. This directory is important and they are part of [Filesystem Hierarchy Standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). But incase if you still want to delete it, login as a `root` user and enter `rm -rf /mnt` it should get deleted.

Comment: When I logged in again thismorning, disk was empty. I must have just not reloaded after unmounting. I was not however able to remove disk as described above... Matlab was instaled to ust/local/matlab, which seems OK reading this: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/… Thank you for your clear explanation making me (and others) feel welcome to the world of Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
# mount -o ro,loop ./R2014a_UNIX.iso /mnt/matlab
```

mounts the filesystem contained in the CD / DVD image R2014a_UNIX.iso at '/mnt/matlab', using the loop device. It doesn't actually copy the data from the .iso image file into the '/mnt/matlab' directory. When a process attempts to access the files that *appear* to be inside the '/mnt/matlab' directory the loop device translates these requests so that they refer to the data that's really inside the .iso image file. The `ro` specifies that the filesystem is read only, so you can't accidentally damage the contents of the .iso. You certainly *don't* want to install stuff into '/mnt/matlab'!

Once you've done the installation and umount '/mnt/matlab', have a look at the contents of '/mnt/matlab' and you'll see that it's empty. And if you want, you can then safely delete '/mnt/matlab'.